# How to get Sum of all distinct values using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have `ComboUniqueId` and this basis I want ComboAmount, my problem is how to get distinct `ComboAmount` on `ComboUniqueId` basis please help me this, my code is below:

ComboUniqueId  it is string

```
decimal FinalTotal = 0;

var ListUnique = this.OrderDetailArr.Select(x => new {
    ComboAmount = x.ComboAmount,
    ComboId = x.ComboId,
    ComboUniqueId = x.ComboUniqueId,
    ItemAddOnsArr = x.ItemAddOnsArr,
    TotalPrice =  x.TotalPrice
}).Distinct(x=> x.ComboUniqueId);

for (int i = 0; i < ListUnique.Length; i++)
{
    FinalTotal += ListUnique[i].TotalPrice;
    if(ListUnique[i].ComboId != null)
    {
        FinalTotal = ListUnique[i].ComboAmount;
    }
    if (ListUnique[i].ItemAddOnsArr != null)
    {
        for (int g = 0; g < this.OrderDetailArr[i].ItemAddOnsArr.Length; g++)
        {
            FinalTotal += this.OrderDetailArr[i].ItemAddOnsArr[g].AddOnTotalPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `this.OrderDetailArr` has duplicates and you want them removing.

You can do this with code similar to the following, instead of creating an anonymous object:

```
var ListUnique = this.OrderDetailArr
    // Group on the ComboUniqueId, you'll get 1 key with multiple values for duplicates
    .GroupBy(m => m.ComboUniqueId)
    // By retrieving the First(), you're limiting your result set to 1 per the group
    .Select(m => m.First());
```

The remainder of your code should work in place.

There's no need to create a new anonymous type here (`.Select(.. => new {..})`) because you're only pulling properties from the source anyway, so you might as well keep it.

If you're set on using `Distinct`, you'd need an `EqualityComparer<T>` for your object type, that only looks at the `ComboUniqueId` property of the object to compare equality, you could then use that in a `Distinct` method as per your original code. Note that it again would not work with your anonymous type.